# NodeJs and Typescript: development mode does not recognize custom types

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, nodemon

The error is that when I run with Nodemon the server in development mode sends me the following error due to my custom types:

**Property 'returnTo' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial'.**

[Error: Property 'returnTo' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf5jx.png)

This file is named express-session-types.d.ts and has the following code:

[express-session-types.d.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Chv.png)

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrT6Y.png)

My package.json scripts:
[My package.json scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cjZ6.png)

Comment: Hi Derian and welcome to stack overflow. You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to frame your question more accordingly to the community standards and increase the chances of getting a good answer. For example: Images are not a good way to share code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to force import the types into my server.ts file or project startup file as follows:

```sh
import * as sessionTypes from './types/express-session-types';
```

Where express-session-types is my module file with extension .d.ts where the property is declared.